# facebook comments plugin to show comments dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

i use facebook comments plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

for every page in my site

and i show the facebook comments by fetching from json request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=abc.com/
```

so when i update comment in facebook plugin, i would like to get the comments in my site to get dynamically updated

my code in controller

```
@fb_res=HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=abc.com/')
fb_json=JSON.parse(@fb_res)
@fb_comment = fb_json["abc.com/"]["comments"]["data"].map {|x| [x["from"]["id"],x["message"],x["from"]["name"]]}
```

my views :

```
  <% @fb_comment.each do |fb| %>
  <li>
    <div class="pic_commnt">
    <div class="pic">
    <div class="pic_image">
    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<%= fb[0].to_s %>/picture?type=square" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span class="pic_name"><%= fb[2].to_s %></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pic_comments">
    <p>
    "<%= fb[1].to_s %>"
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
```

i would like to get this section updated dynamically